# Was recently leaked and wondering what this site can do w/ my info

Tags: email, data-leakage

I was recently notified by Guardio that some of my info was leaked to 'Combolist' and when I clicked on the link I was brought to this.. https://cracked.io/Forum-Combolists--297?page=2.

I'm completely horrified at what I saw and didn't completely understand.  I'm wondering how dangerous this is exactly. From what I gather this is a collection of stolen emails, passwords, usernames, etc and I didn't want to interact w/ anyone from this site as I'm legitimately scared of being sought out by a crazy.

- How are these sites readily available?
- Since they are easily found, why are they not stopped?
- I understand when one goes down another goes up, but how can I defend myself a little more properly I guess?

Comment: This pretty usual, cybercriminals often publicly leak such data to cause mayhem

Answer (score 1):

A list containing your email and passwords will be used in a [dictionary attack](https://www.crowdstrike.com/cybersecurity-101/brute-force-attacks/) to attempt to access various accounts. This can be serious depending on if you recycle credentials on apps that contain high-value information. Once into your account, an attacker can change your account verification methods, locking you out of the account permanently.

The best course of action is to change your email and passwords for your accounts ASAP and activate 2-factor authentication.

**Some things you can do to mitigate the fallout of such attacks going forward**

- compartmentalize your web app credentials, the social media accounts should use psudo login info from temp mail & VoIP number so that if they are compromised they can be changed without leading to other more important accounts like bank or cloud provider logins
- use a password manager to automate the creation of powerful passwords
- organize your real friends and family in text threads and share your content with them in that way, your contacts can be used to spread malware or perpetuate phishing campaigns weaponizing familiarity.
- and as I've mentioned previously, activate 2-factor authentication on everything possible, this way authentication to what's important will be a combination of someone you are, something you know, and something you have

Comment: Try not to recommend specific products. It can come off as an ad or spam.

Comment: Can you expand on the "compartmentalize your web app credentials" section? I'm not sure what you mean or how it would help

Comment: By "compartmentalize credentials" I meant to categorize credentials according to the apps they are meant to be used in. For example, password manager tags, only saving fake numbers and emails in a browser password manager, or having a password generation method for social media logins while allowing other passwords to be automatically generated.